# JQuery multiple classes automatization

Tags: jquery, wordpress, loops

I have multiple post in loop in WordPress and counter, so I can give specific class to every post.

In JQuery I need to add click function so every post open his div, which has same number after class like this:

```
document.getElementById("copyButton1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget1"));
  $('.showclip1').addClass('showedclip');
});
document.getElementById("copyButton2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget2"));
  $('.showclip2').addClass('showedclip');
});
document.getElementById("copyButton3").addEventListener("click", function() {
  copyToClipboard(document.getElementById("copyTarget3"));
  $('.showclip3').addClass('showedclip');
});
```

Since I have more and more posts, I need to do it in some loop in jquery as well even because if I call non-exist Id, all js falls down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding what you're saying correctly, you could try something like this:

```
$(document).on('click','[id^="copyButton"]',function(event){
// this refs all elements that have an id 
// starting with copyButton whether or not
// they have been loaded yet
  var index=this.id.replace("copyButton",'');
  $(".showClip"+index).addClass('showedclip');
});
```

The above will apply to all elements that start with `copyButton` whether or not they exist yet.  You can (and should) keep it outside of any loop, and wrap it with `$(document).ready`.  It should work provided you don't change your selectors.  If you do, u will need to modify accordingly.

Comment: Hi, index has to be without ";" and it works awesome! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @MichalBěhal - right you are.  That was a typo.  Will fix.